# VBA Code to apply filter based on user inputboxes for column alpha-numeric and date

Tags: vba, date, input, autofilter

I would like to write vba code that asks the user "which column" they want to filter; and then "what date" they want to filter that column by (ie any date after mm/dd/yyyy)

Something like:

```
Sub FilterByInput()

Dim iPutFound As Range
Dim mycol As String
Dim mydate As String

mycol = Application.InputBox("Enter alpha-numeric of Column to be filtered -ie. AP3", Type:=2)
mycol = Range(mycol & 1).Column
mydate = Application.InputBox("Enter date since last update was ran- mm/dd/yyyy", Type:=2)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$DK$11000").AutoFilter Field:=mycol, Criteria1:=">" & mydate, Operator:=xlFilterValues

'The code will resume with copying and pasting the filtered results to another sheet, etc

End Sub
```

I receive a run-time error: "Autofilter method of range class failed." My header row is on row 3.  I tried turning filters off before running code but that didn't work either.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's what I did with the edit:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet   
Dim iPutFound As Range  
Dim mycol As String  
Dim myrng As Range  
Dim mydate As String  

mycol = Application.InputBox("Enter alpha-numeric of Column to be filtered -ie. M", Type:=2)  
Set myrng = Range(mycol & 1).Column
mydate = Application.InputBox("Enter date since last update was ran- mm/dd/yyyy", Type:=2)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Range(mycol & 1).Column.AutoFilter Field:=mycol, Criteria1:=">" & mydate, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: try `ActiveSheet.Range(mycol & 1).column`  That is the correct way to find the column number equivalent. just make sure what ever column you use, only use the column string not number

Comment: Not sure I did it right, but still can't get it to run:

Comment: This issue is above my knowledge, sorry I can't be more help

Comment: @A Cohen Thanks for trying  :)